# Container URLs with querystring, is it RESTFul?

Tags: rest, http

Suppose I have a container which is a resource containing a set of resources, for example:

```
http://www.example.com/persons
```

returns all persons

Now if I have want that it doesn't return me all persons but only a subset meeting a certain criteria like `http://www.example.com/persons?age=18`

is such a URL adhears to the RESTFul convention ?

Comment: Yes, that adheres to the rest convention

Comment: I don't think so, GET is idempotent, i.e. doing a GET thousands of time of that URL shouldn't return different results, in this case, it can, if new people are added to the container, am I missing or not understanding something ?

Comment: That's not what idempotent means.  review https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.2

Comment: You are mixing different and unrelated concepts, the fact that GET is idempotent just tells you that you you are not going to cause side effects  when you do a GET on them multiple times, but the returned resources CAN and WILL be different if they have changed.  The query parameter in this case is part of the url and it's completely fine to use it (or them) to get a subset of the resources, that's  a pretty common way to filter them when using resfful (or rest-like) APIs.

Comment: In RFC 3986, it says that ""The query component contains non-hierarchical data that, along with data in the path component (Section 3.3), serves to identify a resource"", in this case, it is not identifying one resource but a set of resource

Comment: Suppose I do a post on ""http://www.example.com/persons?age=18"" with a representation of a ""person"" object, how should the container interpret this, should the newly created ""person"" object be available when doing a GET on ""http://www.example.com/persons""